# Authentication on local-to-local CouchDB continuous replication

Tags: security, couchdb, replication

I'm trying to set up a continuous replication job on a single-server deployment of CouchDB 2.2, from a local db to a local db, without spreading a user's password around.

I can get replication working with by creating a document in the `_replicator` db of this form:

```js
{
  "_id": "my-replication-job-id",
  "_rev": "1-5dd6ea5ad8479bb30f84dac02aaba59c",   
  "source": "http://username:password@localhost:5984/source_db_name",   
  "target": "http://username:password@localhost:5984/target_db_name",
  "continuous": true,
  "owner": "user-that-created-this-job"
}
```

Is there any way to do this without inserting the user's password in plaintext (or a base64-encoded version of it) in the `source` and `target` fields of my replication job? This is all running on the same server... both databases and the replication job itself.

I see that Couch 2.2 added the [ability for replication jobs to maintain their authenticated state using a cookie](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/replicator.html#replicator/auth_plugins) but my understanding is the username and password are still be necessary in order to initiate an authenticated session with the source and target DB's.

I should add that I have `require_valid_user = true` configured.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that by specifying a hostname (eg: `localhost:5984`), you aren't actually doing local-to-local replication. Instead, you should just specify the database names.

Comment: Also, only admins can access the docs in system databases like `_replicator`, does that address any of your security concerns?

Comment: I would also refer to [the documentation about "delegations"](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/replicator.html#delegations) if you need to configure a replication to take place under the context of users other than the one you are already authenticated against. It allows you to specify a custom `user_ctx` that can take users or roles.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @DominicBarnes. When I try just specifying the database name for `source` and/or `target`, I get an error in the logs: `Could not open file /Users/mfogel/Library/Application Support/CouchDB2/var/lib/couchdb/<databasename>.couch: no such file or directory`. It's true - that file doesn't exist. The DB appears to be sharded at the filesystem level but the replicator isn't respecting that... best I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It may be this issue:

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1550

Which has now been fixed, and I believe it will appear in 2.2.1

Comment: I'll give it a try once 2.2.1 is officially released, thanks